# PnPjs alternatives for .NET

Tags: development, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, .net, pnp

For developing with the SharePoint REST APIs using JavaScript I always use PnPjs because it's an easy way of getting data from SP.

> PnPjs is a collection of fluent libraries for consuming SharePoint, Graph, and Office 365 REST APIs in a type-safe way.
>
> [image]
>
> <sup>Source: [pnp.github.io/pnpjs](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/)</sup>

My question is now can I use a NuGet library that does the same in .NET *(but without the thenable promises of course)*?

I'll access SharePoint lists using a console application written in C#.

I've searched for alternatives but didn't find anything that looks good. The only thing I find is to write it like code below:

> ```
> using Newtonsoft.Json;  
> using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;  
>   
> namespace REST  
> {  
>     class Program  
>     {  
>         static void Main(string[] args)  
>         {  
>             HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("Site URL/_api/web/lists/getByTitle(List Name')/items");  
>           
>             endpointRequest.Method = "GET";  
>             endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";  
>             NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");  
>             endpointRequest.Credentials = cred;  
>             HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();  
>             try  
>             {  
>                 WebResponse webResponse = endpointRequest.GetResponse();  
>                 Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();  
>                 StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);  
>                 string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();  
>                 JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(response);  
>                 JArray jarr = (JArray)jobj["d"]["results"];  
>                 foreach (JObject j in jarr)  
>                 {  
>                     Console.WriteLine(j["Title"]+" "+j["Body"]);  
>                 }  
>                   
>                 responseReader.Close();  
>                 Console.ReadLine();             
>             }  
>             catch (Exception e)  
>             {  
>                 Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message); Console.ReadLine();  
>             }       
>         }  
>     }  
> }
> ```
>
> <sup>Source: [C# corner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/working-with-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-in-a-C-Sharp-managed-code/)</sup>

Comment: Why not use the SharePoint CSOM API https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code? Possibly together with PNP (if needed) https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pnp even with .NET.

If you want an alternative you can use [CSOM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code), the .NET version of [JSOM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-javascript-library-code-in-sharepoint)